# How to compare value in where clause with max value for an ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I am trying to make a selection from a lot of different tables, and for one of the constraints the primary key can not have an item associated to it that has a date within the last 30 days. However, it is possible for the primary key to have multiple items associated with it.

The issue that i currently face is when there are multiple items associated, one that is within the date range and one that is outside, it is still getting returned. I want it to be excluded if any of the associated item's dates are within the past 30 days.

How can i make the program to fetch all the items instead of just one at a time?

Thanks!

Comment: did the solution below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Using `NOT IN`

```
select *
from table
where id not in (select id from table where datefield > dateadd(day,-30,getdate())
```

This only returns records from the `table` where the `id` doesn't have a record where the `datefield` is more than 30 days old. You likely need a join too since you reference *a lot of different tables*. Something like...

```
select *
from table
where id not in (select id
                 from table
                 inner join table2 on table2.refid = table.id
                 where table2.datefield > dateadd(day,-30,getdate())
```